# Aligning two images on bottom left and bottom right of a div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a justified block of text within the footer of a bootstrap html page.
Now i'd like to add two images with the same height but different widths to under the text and at aligned to either side.

```
<footer>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <span class="copyright">Copyright &copy; Bla Bla 2015</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="disclaimer">
            <span>Der ritter überladen ie des den der kâmen und. Daz ane waz ie der waz Tristan, lant ende, wol daz, schaden nieman lant benaeme sîne ze der wîp, schaden liute ie. Und diz von, trôstes wârheit haete nieman unde. Iuch meistiu alsô lande ze belanget, vol niht verluren, meistiu er schedelîchen swer ritter ze ie niht ende swer</span>
                <img id="logo_left" src="http://s1.postimg.org/j4mav1ikb/logo_left.jpg" class="img-responsive img-left" alt="">
                <img id="logo_right" src="http://s1.postimg.org/bda6a83sr/logo_right.jpg" class="img-responsive img-right" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <ul class="list-inline legallinks">
                <li>
                    <a href="#modal_legal1" class="legal-link" data-toggle="modal">Legal1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#modal_legal2" class="legal-link" data-toggle="modal">Legal2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i cannot get it to work properly

here is the jsfiddle:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rf15qbup/1/)

thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `float` property to both `#logo_left` and `#logo_right` ID's.

```
#logo_left {
  float:left;
 }

#logo_right {
  float:right; 
}
```

and also add below code above the image tag(after the span text)

```
<br style="clear:both"/>
```

http://jsbin.com/pesegebubo/edit

Answer (score 1):

What janaspage said is right. You should wrap text around p not span. Then take a look of img classes. Its img-responsive and img-left. I have no idea why there is img-left class. Instead of that you can use bootstrap class called pull-left (and pull-right). So:

- use p tag instead of span
- change img-left to pull-left and change img-right to pull-right

Hope it helps

EDIT: I relized you have to add "clear: both;"  to your ul class ".list-inline". Without that your links will be between images when screen is small.